# async http request on Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, asynchronous, request

Does anybody know how to make http request from Google App Engine without waiting a response?
It should be like a push data with http without latency for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [this section of the AppEngine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Async requests still block the response from being sent.  It just allows you to do processing while waiting for other data to arrive.  At least that is what I get from the documentation.

Comment: @envalid: my impression is that OP does not care about getting a response. He characterized it as a 'push' operation.

Comment: `If any URL Fetch requests are pending when the request handler exits, the application server waits for all remaining requests to either return or reach their deadline before returning a response to the user.` Src: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html

Comment: @envalid: Yes, that is true, but it is only relevant if the code that initiates the request really cares about getting a response. If it is pushing data somewhere, then making the request at all should be sufficient. He can give the fetch a sufficiently-low timeout such that it won't impede his handler for exiting in a timely fashion.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It realy helped me. I'd found it before but my problem was that I tried it on developer server. This functionality doesn't work as it could be expected on dev server. It works only on deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the taskqueue. If you're just pushing data, there's no sense in waiting for the response.

Comment: @Triptich: Yeah! I've tried it. But there is one disadvantage. When you use taskqueue you spend more cpu time in compare with Asynchronous Requests. Thanks!

Comment: @Vyalov That may be so, but you should consider that CPU time is very cheap, and there are other benefits to using task queues.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is in the request handler enqueue a task with whatever data was received (using the [deferred library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html)).  As soon as the task has been enqueued successfully you can return a '200 OK' response and be ready for the next push.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by setting doing a URLFetch and setting a very low value for the deadline parameter. I put 0.1 as my value, so 100ms. You need to wrap the URLFetch in a try/catch also since the request will timeout.